# How to explain await/async Synchronization Context switching behavior

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, using, synchronizationcontext

There are a couple of things (but 1 main thing) that I don't understand about the behavior of the following code.

Can someone help explain this?

It's actually pretty simple code - just one regular method calling an async method. And in the async method I use a using block to try to temporarily change the SynchronizationContext.

At different points in the code, I probe for the current SynchronizationContext.

Here are my questions:

1. When execution reaches position "2.1" the context has changed to
       Context #2. Okay. Then, because we hit an `await`, a Task is
       returned and execution jumps back to position "1.2". Why then, at
       position 1.2, does the context not "stick" at Context #2?
   Maybe there's some magic going on here with the using statement and async methods?
2. At position 2.2, why is the context not Context #2? Shouldn't the context be carried over into the "continuation" (the statements after `await`)?

---

**Code:**

```
    public class Test
    {
        public void StartHere()
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());

            this.logCurrentSyncContext("1.1"); // Context #1
            Task t = f();
            this.logCurrentSyncContext("1.2"); // Context #1, why not Context #2?
            t.Wait();
            this.logCurrentSyncContext("1.3"); // Context #1
        }


        private async Task f()
        {
            using (new ThreadPoolSynchronizationContextBlock())
            {
                this.logCurrentSyncContext("2.1");  // Context #2
                await Task.Delay(7000);
                this.logCurrentSyncContext("2.2");  // Context is NULL, why not Context #2?
            }

            this.logCurrentSyncContext("2.3");  // Context #1
        }


        // Just show the current Sync Context. Pass in some kind of marker so we know where, in the code, the logging is happening

        private void logCurrentSyncContext(object marker)
        {
            var sc = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(marker + " Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " SyncContext: " + (sc == null? "null" : sc.GetHashCode().ToString()));
        }

        public class ThreadPoolSynchronizationContextBlock : IDisposable
        {
            private static readonly SynchronizationContext threadpoolSC = new SynchronizationContext();

            private readonly SynchronizationContext original;

            public ThreadPoolSynchronizationContextBlock()
            {
                this.original = SynchronizationContext.Current;
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(threadpoolSC);
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(this.original);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Results:**

```
1.1 Thread: 9 SyncContext: 37121646 // I call this "Context #1"
2.1 Thread: 9 SyncContext: 2637164 // I call this "Context #2"
1.2 Thread: 9 SyncContext: 37121646
2.2 Thread: 11 SyncContext: null
2.3 Thread: 11 SyncContext: 37121646
1.3 Thread: 9 SyncContext: 37121646
```

Comment: 2.2: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,2976

Comment: 1.2: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs,320

Comment: It seems like your context block gets under GC. Did you check the `Dispose` call time?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "under GC". The Dispose method gets called only one time - by Thread #11 at the end of the using block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2.2` Is quite simple to explain, `1.2` not as easy.

The reason `2.2` prints `null` is due to when you `await` using the default (`new SynchronizationContext`) or `null` SynchronizationContext, the `Post` method will get called passing in the continuation delegate, this [is scheduled on the ThreadPool](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/synchronizationcontext.cs,131). It makes no effort to restore the current instance, it relies on the current `SynchronizationContext` being `null` for these continuations when they run on the ThreadPool (which it is). To be clear, because you are not using `.ConfigureAwait(false)` your continuation will get posted to the captured context as you are expecting, but the `Post` method in this implementation doesn't preserve/flow the same instance.

To fix this (i.e. make your context "sticky"), you could inherit from `SynchronizationContext`, and overload the `Post` method to call `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(this)` with the posted delegate (using `Delegate.Combine(...)`). Also, the internals treat `SynchronizationContext` instances the same as `null` in most places, so if you want to play with this stuff, always create an inheriting implementation.

For `1.2`, this actually surprised me also, as my understanding was that this would call the underlying state machine (along with all the internals from `AsyncMethodBuilder`), but it would be called synchronously while maintaining its `SynchronizationContext`.

I think what we are seeing here is explained [in this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext/), and it's to do with ExecutionContext being captured and restored inside of the `AsyncMethodBuilder` / async state machine, this is protecting and preserving the calling `ExecutionContext` and hence `SynchronizationContext`. Code for this [can been seen here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs,320) (thanks @VMAtm).